# Updating iteration for story using Rally SDK

Tags: extjs, rally

I have already referred to this: [create/update user story using rally app sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539235/create-update-user-story-using-rally-app-sdk)

Here's my code:

```
 _update_iteration_of_parent: function(pOID, iteration){ //iteration is the OID of iteration to be added.
console.log("Updating Iteration ",'/iteration/'+iteration);
var me = this;
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'User Story',
            success: function (model){

                    var that = this;

                    //console.log("objectid #",objectid," latestpsi ",latestpsi);
                    this.model = model;
                    var id = pOID;
                    console.log("_readRecord ",id);
                    this.model.load(id,{
                        fetch: ['Name','Iteration'],
                        callback: function (record, operation){
                            //console.log('name .. ', record.get('Name'));
                            if(operation.wasSuccessful()){
                                console.log('Iteration ',record.get('Iteration'));
                                record.set('Iteration','/iteration/'+iteration);

                                record.save({
                                    callback: function(record,operation){
                                        if(operation.wasSuccessful()){
                                            console.log("Operation Successful");

                                        }
                                        else
                                        console.log("Not");
                                    },
                                    scope: this,
                                });

                            }
                        },
                        scope: this
                    });

        }
        });


}
```

I am not able to update the iteration, and it always logs "Not" indicating it was not a success when      record.set('Iteration','/iteration/'+iteration) is called. There is no problem in getting the values for pOID and iteration.

Comment: Your code looks pretty good... the problem is likely that the specified iteration is not in the correct project or something like that.  You should be able to see the response in your browser's dev tools network tab and inspect the Errors returned.  You can also get them like this: operation.getError().errors

Comment: @KyleMorse so if the specified iteration is not in the correct project, how do i set it to that user story?. This is the error returned:

Could not set value for Iteration: Could not set iteration for the parent object directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is called `_update_iteration_of_parent` which indicates that you are trying to set Iteration on a parent story. If this is true, that explains the failure to set iteration. It is not possible to schedule a parent (epic) story for Iteration in UI or API.